# Track all coins on bsc

Tags: token, blockchain, binance, bsc

I want to track all coins and tokens that deployed to BSC. But I don't have a solid idea to achieve this.

Basicly, I want to get all coins on BSC and filter them as I want and track them.

So my question is, is it possible to fetch all coins data(at least coins that deployed in 1 year) on BSC and use this data as my purpose?

EDİT:

https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=stats&action=tokens&type=bep20&apikey=apikey

I tried that but its giving error

Comment: [For example here you can find PYthon scripts that track new trading pairs](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/index.html)

Comment: Yeah, actually it was more easy if I would just get new coins. But I also want the ones already deployed in one year.

Comment: You will also find a script to get old coins

Comment: I really couldn't find any solid documentation or solution. Yet the one you recommend to me based on pairs and uniswap. I used an endpoint like that: https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=stats&action=tokens&type=bep20&apikey=apikey